# R: How to add the values of each objects in a list of different objects

Tags: r

I am attempting to count the values associated with each different object/team to determine which team has the highest value. 
I have a created a matrix where one column states the home team, one column is the visiting team and the last column gives the value of 1, 0 or NA. If the value is 1 the home team won, 0 the visiting team wins, and NA means a tie occurred.

Here is what my matrix (winners) looks like:

```
      home_team      visit_team     home_outcomes
 [1,] "Brewers"      "Marlins"      "1"          
 [2,] "Rockies"      "Giants"       "0"          
 [3,] "Rangers"      "Cardinals"    "0"          
 [4,] "Nationals"    "Cubs"         "1"          
 [5,] "Braves"       "Nationals"    "1"          
 [6,] "Pirates"      "Reds"         "1"          
 [7,] "Rays"         "Mariners"     "1"          
 [8,] "Orioles"      "Dodgers"      "0"          
 [9,] "Marlins"      "Reds"         "1"          
[10,] "Mets"         "Royals"       "1"
```

The full matrix is 703 rows.

I am looking to count the values and see which team has won the most amount of games.

I have tried an array of methods to tackle this, but I am brand new to R and am a bit confused. Any help is appreciated!

okay. I am literally brand new to R and any coding in general, so when asked to dput() my code, I believe this is what I am being asked to do. Thanks everyone! Great community!

```
    structure(c("Brewers", "Rockies", "Rangers", "Nationals", "Braves", 
"Pirates", "Rays", "Orioles", "Marlins", "Mets", "Rockies", "Padres", 
"Royals", "Rangers", "White", "Reds", "Dodgers", "Tigers", "Yankees", 
"Cubs", "Yankees", "Tigers", "Athletics", "Tigers", "Mariners", 
"Brewers", "Brewers", "Reds", "Cubs", "Rays", "Indians", "Twins", 
"Rays", "Angels", "Marlins", "Pirates", "Rockies", "Orioles", 
"Indians", "Astros", "Blue", "Reds", "Padres", "Blue", "Rangers", 
"Royals", "Athletics", "Tigers", "Brewers", "Diamondbacks", "Orioles", 
"Phillies", "Red", "Mets", "Orioles", "Athletics", "Mets", "Padres", 
"Reds", "Phillies", "Rangers", "Cubs", "Phillies", "Orioles", 
"Red", "Giants", "Red", "Cardinals", "Angels", "Padres", "Yankees", 
"Yankees", "Rangers", "Cardinals", "Rockies", "Marlins", "White", 
"Mets", "Rockies", "Diamondbacks", "Cubs", "Rockies", "Marlins", 
"Blue", "White", "Yankees", "Indians", "Rangers", "Red", "Orioles", 
"Marlins", "Rays", "Rangers", "Giants", "Cubs", "Dodgers", "Nationals", 
"Orioles", "Diamondbacks", "Cubs", "Braves", "Cubs", "Tigers", 
"Astros", "Padres", "Dodgers", "Cardinals", "Cubs", "Twins", 
"Cardinals", "Tigers", "Reds", "Marlins", "Astros", "Blue", "Giants", 
"Giants", "Yankees", "Mets", "Dodgers", "Rangers", "Reds", "Phillies", 
"Padres", "White", "Braves", "Reds", "Padres", "Rangers", "Nationals", 
"Cardinals", "White", "Pirates", "Red", "Twins", "Tigers", "Nationals", 
"Braves", "Reds", "Marlins", "Astros", "Orioles", "Diamondbacks", 
"Athletics", "Royals", "Athletics", "Cubs", "Rockies", "Orioles", 
"Mets", "Rays", "Angels", "Reds", "Tigers", "Padres", "Dodgers", 
"Cubs", "Mets", "Angels", "Athletics", "Astros", "White", "Reds", 
"Athletics", "Braves", "Athletics", "Orioles", "Twins", "Rockies", 
"Reds", "Reds", "Rays", "Diamondbacks", "Marlins", "Yankees", 
"Astros", "Rockies", "Orioles", "Indians", "Cardinals", "Padres", 
"Mets", "Royals", "Marlins", "Tigers", "Marlins", "Braves", "Rays", 
"Red", "Rangers", "Mariners", "Marlins", "Athletics", "Cardinals", 
"Mariners", "Diamondbacks", "Red", "Tigers", "White", "Royals", 
"Twins", "Rays", "Red", "Rays", "White", "Twins", "Giants", "Mets", 
"Padres", "Giants", "Cubs", "Mariners", "Giants", "Rays", "Dodgers", 
"Blue", "Phillies", "Cardinals", "Mariners", "Cubs", "Cardinals", 
"Yankees", "Indians", "Athletics", "Royals", "Rangers", "Rangers", 
"Mets", "Yankees", "Astros", "Dodgers", "White", "Athletics", 
"Marlins", "Dodgers", "Brewers", "Rockies", "Nationals", "Phillies", 
"Marlins", "Angels", "Red", "Cubs", "Rockies", "Athletics", "Giants", 
"Mets", "Orioles", "Tigers", "Pirates", "Yankees", "Padres", 
"Cardinals", "Astros", "Athletics", "Marlins", "Twins", "Nationals", 
"Braves", "Yankees", "Cardinals", "Mets", "Blue", "Phillies", 
"Twins", "Orioles", "Royals", "Phillies", "Twins", "Orioles", 
"Red", "Brewers", "Dodgers", "Cardinals", "Orioles", "Yankees", 
"Athletics", "Mets", "Rays", "Brewers", "Royals", "Dodgers", 
"Pirates", "Nationals", "Mets", "Dodgers", "Red", "Cardinals", 
"Twins", "Cardinals", "Blue", "Braves", "Giants", "Twins", "Cubs", 
"Indians", "Cardinals", "Royals", "Giants", "Phillies", "Mariners", 
"Reds", "Royals", "Giants", "Astros", "Braves", "Rays", "Padres", 
"Blue", "Marlins", "Rockies", "Diamondbacks", "Reds", "White", 
"Mets", "Rays", "White", "Mets", "Padres", "Astros", "Angels", 
"Padres", "Pirates", "Pirates", "Reds", "Orioles", "Athletics", 
"Giants", "Braves", "Twins", "Rays", "Brewers", "Nationals", 
"Marlins", "Twins", "Phillies", "Giants", "Athletics", "Pirates", 
"Mets", "Astros", "Rays", "Yankees", "Twins", "Rangers", "Diamondbacks", 
"Yankees", "Angels", "Cubs", "Indians", "Tigers", "White", "Tigers", 
"Cardinals", "Brewers", "Diamondbacks", "Mariners", "Nationals", 
"Marlins", "White", "Tigers", "Rockies", "Diamondbacks", "Cubs", 
"Indians", "Marlins", "Rockies", "Padres", "Nationals", "Dodgers", 
"Brewers", "Rockies", "Braves", "Phillies", "Twins", "Yankees", 
"Cubs", "Rangers", "Mets", "Tigers", "Astros", "Rangers", "Yankees", 
"Giants", "Padres", "Orioles", "Yankees", "Phillies", "Astros", 
"Royals", "Cardinals", "Rockies", "Mariners", "Angels", "Cardinals", 
"Dodgers", "White", "Nationals", "Red", "Royals", "Tigers", "Rangers", 
"Red", "Athletics", "Rays", "Angels", "Phillies", "Brewers", 
"Rangers", "Royals", "Phillies", "Pirates", "Tigers", "Nationals", 
"Rays", "White", "Red", "Rays", "Giants", "Giants", "Royals", 
"Twins", "Red", "Nationals", "All", "Astros", "Pirates", "Brewers", 
"White", "Royals", "Cubs", "Tigers", "Brewers", "Yankees", "White", 
"Diamondbacks", "Angels", "Diamondbacks", "Indians", "Blue", 
"Angels", "Marlins", "Indians", "Blue", "Giants", "Rays", "Twins", 
"Red", "Phillies", "Cubs", "Nationals", "Twins", "Indians", "Rays", 
"Pirates", "Padres", "Mets", "Marlins", "Rangers", "Braves", 
"Rays", "Rangers", "White", "Braves", "Yankees", "Cubs", "Blue", 
"Mets", "White", "Brewers", "Royals", "Angels", "Indians", "Nationals", 
"Nationals", "Blue", "Rays", "Indians", "Pirates", "Mets", "Marlins", 
"Marlins", "Marlins", "Giants", "Yankees", "Giants", "Nationals", 
"Mets", "Indians", "Angels", "Yankees", "Marlins", "Mets", "Rockies", 
"Orioles", "Indians", "Blue", "Twins", "Orioles", "Blue", "Angels", 
"Phillies", "Blue", "Athletics", "Brewers", "Astros", "Orioles", 
"Mets", "Athletics", "Tigers", "Mariners", "Dodgers", "Rays", 
"Yankees", "Phillies", "Reds", "Brewers", "Red", "White", "Rays", 
"Tigers", "Indians", "White", "Red", "Twins", "Marlins", "Nationals", 
"Mariners", "Blue", "Marlins", "Mariners", "Dodgers", "Mets", 
"Marlins", "Rangers", "Marlins", "Dodgers", "Dodgers", "Padres", 
"Rays", "Rays", "Diamondbacks", "Marlins", "Indians", "Marlins", 
"Astros", "Angels", "Tigers", "Tigers", "Twins", "White", "Phillies", 
"Diamondbacks", "Mariners", "Indians", "Dodgers", "Athletics", 
"Royals", "Brewers", "Dodgers", "Astros", "Brewers", "Reds", 
"Nationals", "Angels", "Astros", "Indians", "Athletics", "Padres", 
"Nationals", "Yankees", "Blue", "Red", "Cubs", "Brewers", "Rangers", 
"Pirates", "Mets", "Yankees", "Reds", "Cubs", "Rangers", "Pirates", 
"Rays", "Yankees", "Royals", "Giants", "Royals", "Cubs", "Mariners", 
"Astros", "Rockies", "Mets", "Pirates", "Reds", "Athletics", 
"Cubs", "Royals", "Giants", "Twins", "Mariners", "Twins", "Rangers", 
"Brewers", "Reds", "Rays", "Orioles", "Red", "Dodgers", "Tigers", 
"Brewers", "Angels", "Astros", "Nationals", "Brewers", "Athletics", 
"Rangers", "Rangers", "Indians", "Mariners", "Yankees", "Cardinals", 
"Royals", "Tigers", "Indians", "Red", "Indians", "Blue", "Tigers", 
"White", "Giants", "Mets", "Rangers", "Diamondbacks", "Athletics", 
"Rays", "Brewers", "Marlins", "Phillies", "Marlins", "Phillies", 
"Diamondbacks", "Brewers", "Red", "Yankees", "Nationals", "Athletics", 
"Astros", "Astros", "Twins", "Giants", "Red", "Marlins", "Blue", 
"Dodgers", "Braves", "Indians", "Blue", "Mets", "Blue", "Diamondbacks", 
"Phillies", "Yankees", "Royals", "Diamondbacks", "Yankees", "Athletics", 
"Dodgers", "Pirates", "Orioles", "Cubs", "Mets", "Phillies", 
"Mets", "Reds", "Rockies", "Red", "Marlins", "Braves", "Royals", 
"Mariners", "Yankees", "Red", "Dodgers", "Dodgers", "Nationals", 
"Indians", "Indians", "Padres", "Marlins", "Twins", "Braves", 
"Astros", "Braves", "Diamondbacks", "Athletics", "Cubs", "Reds", 
"Athletics", "Braves", "Mariners", "Pirates", "Blue", "Blue", 
"Royals", "Cubs", "Giants", "Athletics", "Yankees", "Dodgers", 
"Yankees", "Mariners", "Astros", "Diamondbacks", "Diamondbacks", 
"Brewers", "Mets", "Dodgers", "Braves", "Phillies", "Athletics", 
"Angels", "Mariners", "Reds", "Rockies", "Reds", "Indians", "Nationals", 
"Indians", "Mets", "Rockies", "Rays", "Rockies", "Mets", "Padres", 
"Orioles", "Brewers", "Reds", "Twins", "Indians", "Pirates", 
"Braves", "Astros", "Twins", "Nationals", "Twins", "Blue", "Pirates", 
"Pirates", "Indians", "Mariners", "Mets", "Marlins", "Giants", 
"Cardinals", "Cubs", "Nationals", "Reds", "Mariners", "Dodgers", 
"Reds", "Royals", "Dodgers", "Mets", "Indians", "Athletics", 
"Rays", "Dodgers", "Giants", "Angels", "Indians", "Cardinals", 
"Royals", "Nationals", "Rangers", "Sox", "Athletics", "Rockies", 
"Braves", "Padres", "Marlins", "Rangers", "Twins", "Nationals", 
"Orioles", "Mariners", "Mets", "Mets", "Yankees", "Royals", "Twins", 
"Mariners", "Astros", "Rangers", "Braves", "Athletics", "Astros", 
"Twins", "Angels", "Twins", "Cubs", "Reds", "Yankees", "Tigers", 
"Yankees", "Cubs", "Rays", "Brewers", "Royals", "Cubs", "Giants", 
"Diamondbacks", "Cubs", "Cardinals", "Cardinals", "Twins", "Padres", 
"Dodgers", "Jays", "Braves", "Astros", "Giants", "Twins", "Pirates", 
"Mariners", "Pirates", "Dodgers", "Pirates", "Indians", "Jays", 
"Pirates", "Rockies", "Dodgers", "Padres", "Nationals", "Astros", 
"Cubs", "Athletics", "Twins", "Cubs", "Royals", "Sox", "Diamondbacks", 
"Yankees", "Sox", "Braves", "Sox", "Reds", "Marlins", "Sox", 
"Dodgers", "Cardinals", "Tigers", "Giants", "Marlins", "Mariners", 
"Phillies", "Yankees", "Marlins", "Phillies", "Marlins", "Cubs", 
"Sox", "Mets", "Twins", "Royals", "Yankees", "Yankees", "Mets", 
"Rays", "Giants", "Marlins", "Reds", "Braves", "Cardinals", "Giants", 
"Cubs", "Diamondbacks", "Indians", "Cardinals", "Sox", "Orioles", 
"Brewers", "Orioles", "Athletics", "Yankees", "Nationals", "Indians", 
"Royals", "Diamondbacks", "Indians", "Giants", "Rangers", "Indians", 
"Marlins", "Orioles", "Athletics", "Angels", "Nationals", "Padres", 
"Sox", "Brewers", "Twins", "Astros", "Sox", "Jays", "Royals", 
"Sox", "Padres", "Marlins", "Athletics", "Angels", "Braves", 
"Tigers", "Dodgers", "Twins", "Reds", "Angels", "Phillies", "Jays", 
"Mets", "Pirates", "Brewers", "Jays", "Padres", "Nationals", 
"Indians", "Yankees", "Cardinals", "Mariners", "Braves", "Angels", 
"Diamondbacks", "Phillies", "Rangers", "Twins", "Yankees", "Phillies", 
"Nationals", "Jays", "Orioles", "Athletics", "Reds", "Mets", 
"Royals", "Cubs", "Pirates", "Giants", "Angels", "Indians", "Jays", 
"Mariners", "Tigers", "Tigers", "Yankees", "Jays", "Yankees", 
"Mariners", "Padres", "Brewers", "Phillies", "Padres", "Cardinals", 
"Giants", "Padres", "Sox", "Cubs", "Astros", "Braves", "Cubs", 
"Brewers", "Brewers", "Cubs", "Mets", "Royals", "Mariners", "Tigers", 
"Angels", "Angels", "Nationals", "Mariners", "Angels", "Reds", 
"Indians", "Giants", "Diamondbacks", "Marlins", "Athletics", 
"Dodgers", "Dodgers", "Mets", "Sox", "Athletics", "Braves", "Indians", 
"Brewers", "Mariners", "Marlins", "Cardinals", "Jays", "Twins", 
"Phillies", "Jays", "Cubs", "Pirates", "Angels", "Angels", "Cardinals", 
"Phillies", "Pirates", "Orioles", "Braves", "Brewers", "Tigers", 
"Sox", "Cubs", "Mets", "Angels", "Athletics", "Marlins", "Royals", 
"Sox", "Orioles", "Cubs", "Giants", "Cubs", "Yankees", "Tigers", 
"Indians", "Padres", "Orioles", "Padres", "Rays", "Brewers", 
"Marlins", "Royals", "Braves", "Padres", "Twins", "Marlins", 
"Nationals", "Giants", "Tigers", "Diamondbacks", "Phillies", 
"Brewers", "Diamondbacks", "Sox", "Mets", "Twins", "Diamondbacks", 
"Marlins", "Athletics", "Diamondbacks", "Rays", "Padres", "Twins", 
"Brewers", "Twins", "Pirates", "Royals", "Phillies", "Giants", 
"Reds", "Phillies", "Royals", "Braves", "Tigers", "Tigers", "Marlins", 
"Diamondbacks", "Rangers", "Rangers", "Cardinals", "Athletics", 
"Tigers", "Giants", "Astros", "Royals", "Nationals", "Rockies", 
"Indians", "Sox", "Diamondbacks", "Mets", "Rays", "Royals", "Jays", 
"Nationals", "Royals", "Rockies", "Dodgers", "Twins", "Tigers", 
"Padres", "Braves", "Royals", "Mets", "Diamondbacks", "Rangers", 
"Phillies", "Jays", "Twins", "Rangers", "Jays", "Reds", "Dodgers", 
"Jays", "Rangers", "Cardinals", "Padres", "Phillies", "Royals", 
"Marlins", "Sox", "Pirates", "Sox", "Reds", "Sox", "Phillies", 
"Phillies", "Diamondbacks", "Sox", "Cardinals", "Diamondbacks", 
"Jays", "Tigers", "Rays", "Rockies", "Astros", "Giants", "Rangers", 
"Rays", "Mariners", "Orioles", "Cubs", "Rays", "Rays", "Angels", 
"Twins", "Angels", "Sox", "Mets", "Diamondbacks", "Yankees", 
"Rangers", "Mets", "Rockies", "Astros", "Sox", "Indians", "Tigers", 
"Rangers", "Angels", "Twins", "Angels", "Royals", "Astros", "Sox", 
"Reds", "Angels", "Sox", "Rockies", "Brewers", "Angels", "Braves", 
"Twins", "Yankees", "Mariners", "Rockies", "Dodgers", "Dodgers", 
"Angels", "Tigers", "Orioles", "Astros", "All-Stars", "Rays", 
"Brewers", "Diamondbacks", "Royals", "Tigers", "Brewers", "Jays", 
"Rockies", "Athletics", "Indians", "Braves", "Sox", "Nationals", 
"Sox", "Mariners", "Twins", "Cardinals", "Tigers", "Rangers", 
"Mariners", "Indians", "Indians", "Sox", "Marlins", "Pirates", 
"Dodgers", "Athletics", "Brewers", "Sox", "Phillies", "Dodgers", 
"Marlins", "Brewers", "Tigers", "Jays", "Orioles", "Mariners", 
"Astros", "Marlins", "Indians", "Phillies", "Sox", "Tigers", 
"Royals", "Mets", "Mariners", "Brewers", "Jays", "Marlins", "Phillies", 
"Rockies", "Sox", "Tigers", "Mets", "Phillies", "Tigers", "Dodgers", 
"Tigers", "Sox", "Mariners", "Marlins", "Phillies", "Nationals", 
"Angels", "Dodgers", "Sox", "Nationals", "Cubs", "Brewers", "Sox", 
"Dodgers", "Yankees", "Sox", "Twins", "Yankees", "Yankees", "Cardinals", 
"Rays", "Rangers", "Pirates", "Yankees", "Sox", "Cubs", "Brewers", 
"Rays", "Yankees", "Giants", "Jays", "Athletics", "Cubs", "Indians", 
"Cardinals", "Jays", "Tigers", "Mariners", "Sox", "Astros", "Twins", 
"Mariners", "Indians", "Mets", "Phillies", "Jays", "Diamondbacks", 
"Braves", "Astros", "Jays", "Nationals", "Nationals", "Angels", 
"Reds", "Brewers", "Giants", "Marlins", "Marlins", "Orioles", 
"Cubs", "Rockies", "Sox", "Mets", "Mariners", "Jays", "Twins", 
"Rays", "Royals", "Cubs", "Padres", "Orioles", "Sox", "Rangers", 
"Padres", "Tigers", "Cardinals", "Nationals", "Cubs", "Cardinals", 
"Reds", "Padres", "Brewers", "Dodgers", "Padres", "Sox", "Royals", 
"Brewers", "Mets", "Marlins", "Diamondbacks", "Jays", "Pirates", 
"Reds", "Astros", "Phillies", "Indians", "Royals", "Angels", 
"Marlins", "Tigers", "Brewers", "Tigers", "Sox", "Angels", "Indians", 
"Twins", "Cardinals", "Padres", "Athletics", "Marlins", "Nationals", 
"Brewers", "Pirates", "Astros", "Athletics", "Sox", "Padres", 
"Sox", "Astros", "Rays", "Rockies", "Cardinals", "Brewers", "Orioles", 
"Rays", "Twins", "Giants", "Orioles", "Twins", "Mariners", "Mariners", 
"Mets", "Reds", "Reds", "Royals", "Cardinals", "Yankees", "Pirates", 
"Twins", "Reds", "Athletics", "Royals", "Reds", "Jays", "Mariners", 
"Yankees", "Yankees", "Indians", "Cubs", "Reds", "Sox", "Nationals", 
"Mariners", "Pirates", "Mets", "Twins", "Braves", "Cardinals", 
"Nationals", "Padres", "Mariners", "Padres", "Orioles", "Mets", 
"Sox", "Nationals", "Rangers", "Royals", "Diamondbacks", "Orioles", 
"Giants", "Yankees", "Cardinals", "Rockies", "Sox", "Sox", "Reds", 
"Rays", "Braves", "Tigers", "Diamondbacks", "Jays", "Rangers", 
"Jays", "Reds", "Mets", "Reds", "Dodgers", "Royals", "Phillies", 
"Giants", "Braves", "Rockies", "Dodgers", "Mariners", "Indians", 
"Cubs", "Indians", "Twins", "Jays", "Astros", "Indians", "Nationals", 
"Diamondbacks", "Royals", "Yankees", "Jays", "Dodgers", "Sox", 
"Mets", "Brewers", "Rockies", "Giants", "Rangers", "Cardinals", 
"Pirates", "Giants", "Nationals", "Indians", "Orioles", "Orioles", 
"Giants", "Twins", "Cardinals", "Braves", "Giants", "Tigers", 
"Rockies", "Sox", "Indians", "Braves", "Mets", "Orioles", "Pirates", 
"Cardinals", "Mariners", "Nationals", "Jays", "Indians", "Twins", 
"Angels", "Nationals", "Diamondbacks", "Cubs", "Sox", "Mets", 
"Reds", "Cardinals", "Giants", "Yankees", "Cubs", "Marlins", 
"Reds", "Padres", "Rangers", "Marlins", "Astros", "Athletics", 
"Cardinals", "Mets", "Rangers", "Yankees", "Braves", "Indians", 
"Giants", "Sox", "Marlins", "Sox", "Angels", "Phillies", "1", 
"0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", 
"1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", 
"0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "1", 
"1", NA, "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", 
"1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0", 
"1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", 
"0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", 
"1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", 
"0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", 
"1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", NA, "1", "1", "0", "0", 
"1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", NA, 
"0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", 
"0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", 
"0", "1", "1", "0", NA, "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", 
"0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", 
"0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", 
"0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", 
"1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", 
"0", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", 
"1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", 
"1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", 
"1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", 
"1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", NA, "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", 
"0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", 
"1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", NA, "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", 
"0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "1", 
"1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", 
"1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", 
"1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", 
"1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", 
"1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", NA, "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0", 
"0", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", 
"0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", 
"1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0"), .Dim = c(752L, 
3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("home_team", "visit_team", "home_outcomes"
)))
```

Comment: can you use `dput` on the sample matrix and post the output?

Comment: the most common way is to Split the matrix into two by `home_outcomes`

Comment: It's helpful if you could post your R code, even if it does not work yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a quick piece of code that outputs a data.frame with two columns - one is the name of the team, the other is the number of wins (home or away) that team achieved.

This code assumes you structure your data as you mentioned in your question. I have called the matrix 'myMatrix' but you can substitute this however you like.

`uniqueTeams <- c(myMatrix[,1],myMatrix[,2])
uniqueTeams <- unique(uniqueTeams)`

This first concatonates all the team names in both the home and away team column, then shortens this vector to only include unique values (One vector element per team).

```
numTeams <- length(uniqueTeams)
teamWins <- data.frame("Team Name"=uniqueTeams,"No. of Wins"=rep(0,numTeams))
```

This part calculates the number of unuque teams and creates the data.frame which we will store the results in later.

```
for (i in 1:numTeams){

  temp <- as.matrix(myMatrix[ myMatrix[,1] == uniqueTeams[i] & myMatrix[,3] == "1",3])
  teamWins[i,2] <- nrow(temp)

  temp <- as.matrix(myMatrix[ myMatrix[,2] == uniqueTeams[i] & myMatrix[,3] == "0",3])
  teamWins[i,2] <- teamWins[i,2] + nrow(temp)

}
```

Finally, I loop through each unique team name. Firstly I create a temporary sub matrix for that team, when they were playing at home and  won and assign the number of rows as my 
'No. of Wins' column in the output data frame. I also check if the same team played away and won and add the number of rows in that submatrix to the overall value.

What you are left with is a data.frame with two columns. One is the name of the team, the other the number of overall wins as mentioned earlier.

There may be better ways of tackling this, but this is just what I came up with off the top of my head.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH KEVIN! I kept trying if else statements and staring at my computer screen. This really is a great method at attacking this problem.